# Convert string to grouped by letters

Tags: php

How I can create regex that converts a string to another string which is grouped by letters or numbers:

```
$string = "cucumber";
```

After regex: `ccuumber`

```
$string = "tohothin";
```

After regex: `ttoohhin`

How I can create this with PHP? It is not important with regex, it may be another function.

Comment: what letters order must be in the result? should it be alphabetical order or in order of appearance?

Comment: it is not important, but alphabetic is more suitable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I didn't see an attempt, but I was bored:

```
$result = '';

foreach(array_count_values(str_split($string)) as $letter => $count) {
    $result .= str_repeat($letter, $count);
}
```

Yields: `ccuumber`

Sorting will work, but give a different order:

```
$letters = str_split($string);
sort($letters);
$result = implode('', $letters);
```

Yields: `bccemruu`